# Quantum State Tomography Implementation in IBMQ

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices, state-tomography

I am working to understand quantum state tomography, specifically using the algorithm presented in [PRL 108, 070502](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.070502). This paper is referenced in IBMQ implementations of QST, both in old deprecated [Ignis code](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis/blob/master/qiskit/ignis/verification/tomography/fitters/lstsq_fit.py) (my primary reference so far) and in the new Qiskit Experiments. In the paper, the authors present an algorithm where the basis is changed from measurement results $m_i$ to a noisy density matrix: $$\mu=(1/d)\sum_im_i\sigma_i$$ where the $\sigma_i$'s are the Pauli matrices plus the identity. After this, their "Subproblem 1" speeds up the least squares optimization problem by transforming $\mu$ to a positive semidefinite matrix $\rho$ which is presented as the least squares solution without having to actually perform least squares minimization. However in the IBMQ code I referenced, the algorithm uses traditional least squares optimization directly without performing the basis change, then the PSD rescaling is applied to the result.

Is there a particular reason for this? My assumption is that performing least squares directly will be slower than the basis change proposed in the paper.

I am also not understanding how to produce $m_i$ corresponding to the identity matrix following the algorithm in the paper, which the IBMQ implementation seems to skip, so perhaps this is another motivation?